# dorng parallel computing and store elapsed time negative value in R

Tags: r, time, foreach, parallel-processing

Hello I am studying dorng for parallel computing. 
I want to see the total execution time for each k time and store into dataframe.
However when I see the results stored in the list timetable, elapsed time is negative value which makes no sense to me. What is wrong with my code?

```
library(doParallel)
library(doRNG)
cl <- makeCluster(3); 
registerDoParallel(cl)

registerDoRNG(seed = 11)
tstart_par = proc.time()
time_chain_par = matrix(0, 10, 2)
timetable <- foreach(k=1:10, .options.RNG=11) %dorng%{
    runif(10,0,1)
    runif(10,0,1)
    runif(10,0,1)
    etime_par = proc.time() - tstart_par
}



> timetable
[[1]]
 user    system   elapsed 
  -42.559    -8.004 -1483.762 

[[2]]
 user    system   elapsed 
  -43.179    -8.038 -1484.064 

[[3]]
 user    system   elapsed 
  -42.996    -8.065 -1484.305 

[[4]]
 user    system   elapsed 
  -42.558    -8.004 -1483.761 

[[5]]
     user    system   elapsed 
  -43.178    -8.038 -1484.063 

[[6]]
 user    system   elapsed 
  -42.558    -8.004 -1483.761 

[[7]]
     user    system   elapsed 
  -42.996    -8.064 -1484.304 

[[8]]
     user    system   elapsed 
  -43.178    -8.038 -1484.062 

[[9]]
     user    system   elapsed 
  -42.558    -8.004 -1483.760 

[[10]]
     user    system   elapsed 
  -43.177    -8.038 -1484.061
```

Comment: `Sys.time()` instead of `proc.time()` is a better option in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proc.time()` is reset within clusters, so you are comparing how long your main R process has been running to how long your newly created clusters have been running, giving the negative values. It is better to use the `Sys.time()` function in this situation, which compares back to the central clock. So, to count time from starting the parallel process until each cluster finishes processing:

```
library(doParallel)
library(doRNG)
cl <- makeCluster(3); 
registerDoParallel(cl)

registerDoRNG(seed = 11)
tstart_par = Sys.time()

timetable <- foreach(k=1:10, .options.RNG=11) %dorng%{
  runif(10,0,1)
  runif(10,0,1)
  runif(10,0,1)
  etime_par = Sys.time() - tstart_par
}
stopCluster(cl)

> timetable
[[1]]
Time difference of 2.897783 secs

[[2]]
Time difference of 2.897755 secs

[[3]]
Time difference of 2.899669 secs

[[4]]
Time difference of 2.899365 secs

[[5]]
Time difference of 2.899258 secs

[[6]]
Time difference of 2.900039 secs

[[7]]
Time difference of 2.901185 secs

[[8]]
Time difference of 2.901083 secs

[[9]]
Time difference of 2.901798 secs

[[10]]
Time difference of 2.902622 secs
```

Or for how long each individual cluster ran for you can use proc.time(), but put it inside the function (I increased the number of samples so that it would run longer and you could see the difference):

```
cl <- makeCluster(3); 
registerDoParallel(cl)

registerDoRNG(seed = 11)

time_chain_par = matrix(0, 10, 2)
timetable <- foreach(k=1:10, .options.RNG=11) %dorng%{
  tstart_par = proc.time()
  runif(1000000,0,1)
  etime_par = proc.time() - tstart_par
}
stopCluster(cl)

timetable
[[1]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.148   0.008   0.307 

[[2]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.145   0.008   0.249 

[[3]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.145   0.008   0.325 

[[4]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.062   0.002   0.130 

[[5]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.062   0.002   0.118 

[[6]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.061   0.003   0.110 

[[7]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.062   0.002   0.110 

[[8]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.061   0.003   0.149 

[[9]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.062   0.002   0.117 

[[10]]
   user  system elapsed 
  0.097   0.003   0.169
```